# Removing highly correlated columns of a huge Pyspark dataframe with missing values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, bigdata, correlation

I have a huge dataframe with 6 million rows and 2k columns. I want to remove the highly correlated columns, and many of the columns are super sparse (90%+ missing values). Unfortunately, the Pyspark Correlation does not handle missing values, AFAIK. That's why I had to loop over columns and compute the correlation.

This is the small code to reproduce it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
l = [
    (7, -5, -8, None, 1, 456, 8),
    (2, 9, 7, 4, None, 9, -1),
    (-3, 3, None, 6, 0, 11, 9),
    (4, -1, 6, 7, 82, 99, 54),
]
names = ["colA", "colB", "colC", "colD", "colE", "colF", "colG"]
db = spark.createDataFrame(l, names)
db.show()


#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
#|colA|colB|colC|colD|colE|colF|colG|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
#|   7|  -5|  -8|null|   1| 456|   8|
#|   2|   9|   7|   4|null|   9|  -1|
#|  -3|   3|null|   6|   0|  11|   9|
#|   4|  -1|   6|   7|  82|  99|  54|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

newdb = (
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=db.columns, outputCol="features")
    .setHandleInvalid("keep")
    .transform(db)
)
newdb.show()


#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------------+
#|colA|colB|colC|colD|colE|colF|colG|            features|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------------+
#|   7|  -5|  -8|null|   1| 456|   8|[7.0,-5.0,-8.0,Na...|
#|   2|   9|   7|   4|null|   9|  -1|[2.0,9.0,7.0,4.0,...|
#|  -3|   3|null|   6|   0|  11|   9|[-3.0,3.0,NaN,6.0...|
#|   4|  -1|   6|   7|  82|  99|  54|[4.0,-1.0,6.0,7.0...|
#+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------------+
```

The correlation function cannot handle missing values.

```py
from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation

Correlation.corr(
    dataset=newdb.select("features"), column="features", method="pearson"
).collect()[0]["pearson(features)"].values


# array([ 1.        , -0.59756161,         nan,         nan,         nan,
#        0.79751788,  0.21792969, -0.59756161,  1.        ,         nan,
#               nan,         nan, -0.82202347, -0.40825556,         nan,
#               nan,  1.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,
#               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,  1.        ,
#               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
#               nan,         nan,  1.        ,         nan,         nan,
#        0.79751788, -0.82202347,         nan,         nan,         nan,
#        1.        , -0.06207047,  0.21792969, -0.40825556,         nan,
#               nan,         nan, -0.06207047,  1.        ])
```

I worked around by a `for` loop, but this one does not apply to my big data:

```py
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

df_vector = newdb
num_cols = 7
res = np.ones((num_cols, num_cols), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(1, num_cols):
    for j in range(i):
        feature_pair_df = df_vector.select("features").rdd.map(
            lambda x: Vectors.dense([x[0][i], x[0][j]])
        )
        feature_pair_df = feature_pair_df.filter(
            lambda x: not np.isnan(x[0]) and not np.isnan(x[1])
        )
        corr_matrix = Statistics.corr(feature_pair_df, method="spearman")
        corr = corr_matrix[0, 1]
        res[i, j], res[j, i] = corr, corr
res

#array([[ 1. , -0.8, -1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.8,  0. ],
#       [-0.8,  1. ,  1. , -1. , -0.5, -1. , -0.4],
#       [-1. ,  1. ,  1. , -1. ,  1. , -1. , -0.5],
#       [ 0.5, -1. , -1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ],
#       [ 0.5, -0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  0.5],
#       [ 0.8, -1. , -1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ,  0.4],
#       [ 0. , -0.4, -0.5,  1. ,  0.5,  0.4,  1. ]], dtype=float32)
```

How can I write it such that I can find a correlation matrix for a large dataset? Mapping instead of looping or any similar ideas.

Comment: It seems that you filter missing values in for loop. You can also filter the dataframe before computing correlation. db = db.na.drop() will remove all rows that have missing value on any column

Comment: @ozlemg The problem is that the drop.na should be pairwise, otherwise with a sparse dataframe I have, all rows should be gone!

Comment: @Hadij, I guess you're trying to populate missing values with adjacent and distant columns values. The problem is: after that, does it eventually give the correct correlation matrix or it's just approximation?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I am removing missing ones rather than populating them.

Answer (score 0):

python3

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Compute the percentage of missing values for each column
missing_values = newdb.select([
    (1 - (count(c) / count("*"))).alias(c+"_missing") 
    for c in newdb.columns
])

# Get the list of columns with more than 90% missing values
sparse_columns = missing_values.columns[1:] # exclude the "features" column
sparse_columns = [c for c in sparse_columns if missing_values.select(c).collect()[0][0] >= 0.9]
# Drop the columns with more than 90% missing values
newdb_filtered = newdb.drop(*sparse_columns)
```

This code computes the percentage of missing values for each column and creates a new dataframe `missing_values` with a new column for each original column appended with `_missing` suffix. It then selects the columns that have more than 90% missing values and puts them in a list called `sparse_columns`. Once you have the list of sparse columns, you can drop them from the dataframe using the drop method.

Comment: I don't want to drop columns. I wanted to compute correlation by ignoring missing values and not by removing those columns.